# Какие компоненты интерфейса используются на картинке?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Необходимо создать прокручивающийся список для приложения, наподобие этого:

[image: Нужно с]

Можно ли сделать его с помощью обычного `ListView`?

Здесь  используются `Recyclerview`, или `CardView`?

Подскажите оптимальный вариант реализации такого списка.

Comment: Можно сделать с помощью `ListView` или `RecyclerView` - это два виджета отображения списков. Виджет `CardView` вообще не отображает списки, это декоративный виджет, который рисует "карточку" и на вашем скриншоте он не наблюдается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут используется RecyclerView либо ListView. 
Просто делается кастомный адаптер. В котором два TextView и ImageView.

Comment: Начал делать через ListView, остался вопрос, может вы знаете ответ, как растянуть изобращение по всей площади ImageView? Изображение в высоком разрешении, но почему-то оно не занимает всё прострастранство, выделенное под ImageView, как на примере

Comment: @Opimand в ImageView в xml добавляете android:scaleType="fitXY", или android:scaleType="centerCrop", лучше использовать RecyclerView, а не ListView.